# Delete temporary images when app is closed - Android

Tags: android, android-image

In my application i create new image files from the images that are picked from the gallery. These new image files are the compressed versions of their counterparts in gallery.

When i click the submit `Button` these files are sent to the server. After confirmation of the response from server these temporary files are deleted.

My question is that if i close the app once i have selected the images and before online submission, the temporary (compressed) files stay in memory.

What is the best approach to say have a cleanup method that executes and removes temporary image files if any, when the app is closed. Is overriding `onDestroy()` the right approach?

Comment: Instead of deleting onDestroy(), you can check onCreate() if these temporary files exist, then delete.

Comment: OnDestroy () is right approach and you can also clear Memory of occupied All resources  used in app.

Comment: @DaxeshKhatri yeah but onDestroy() is not called in such case when you go in background and the close the app from "recent apps" window

Comment: use these two method : onSaveInstanceState()  , ondestroy() . write your clear memory code in this method . if app in background and close then onsaveinstance called and direct close app ondestroy called.

Answer (score 1):

```
use these two method :
```

onSaveInstanceState()  , ondestroy() . 
write your clear memory code in this method . if app in background and close then onsaveinstance called and direct close app ondestroy called.

Comment: yep..it works when i write my clean up function in `onSaveInstanceState()` and then call its super class method

Answer (score -1):

Yes, i think for your perticuler situation onDestroy() is good approch. By using onCreate() for delete images will occupy memory untill next time user will start application.